# Refresh detect filter is always true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I'm using this code to determine if my page is refreshed but it's always coming back as true

```
public class RefreshDetectFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    //void  IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshFilter"];
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"] = cookie != null &&
                                                            cookie.Value == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
    }

    //void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("RefreshFilter", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()));
    }
}
```

in my controller I have the attribute and the check

```
[RefreshDetectFilter]
public class UserController : Controller
```

in the action method

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"]) == true)
{
  // page has been refreshed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not setting the cookie early enough in the request for it to have any effect. Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx):

> You must create cookies before the ASP.NET page is rendered to the client. For example, you can write a cookie in a Page_Load event handler but not in a Page_Unload event handler. For more information on the page life cycle see [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Although, if you look at the [MVC life cycle overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf), the action filter events don't really line up with ASP.NET page events so it is difficult to tell without some experimentation. That said, I suspect you need to do:

```
public class RefreshDetectFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    //void  IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshFilter"];
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"] = cookie != null &&
                                                        cookie.Value == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("RefreshFilter", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()));
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** If you set a route value this way, it will end up as a query string parameter of every URL that is generated on the view. It is difficult to tell if that is your intention or an undesired side effect.